# Robotframework: How to use Chromium in Selenium Library with Open Browser?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, chromium

I want to automate tests for a website using Robotframework and Selenium. My test works well with Firefox. However, I would like to use Chromium instead. According to the [documentation for "Open Browser"](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser), it should work for Chrome. But on my Ubuntu machine I can't use that browser out of the box.

Here is a minimal example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Open Browser And Check Title
    Open Browser  about:blank  chromium
    Title Should Be  ${EMPTY}
```

It fails with the following error:

```
ValueError: chromium is not a supported browser.
```

Is there a way to set up chromium for use with Selenium in Robotframework?

**EDIT:** This was originally asked for Selenium2Library. When moving to version 3, they dropped the version number from the name. The question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: On your linked documentation the possible values for the google Chrome browser are googlechrome, gc, and chrome. Why do you use chromium as value?

Comment: It does not work with those, because Chrome is not installed (and will not be).

Comment: Have you tried using "chrom" just to see if that fixes it? I think you simply must use one of the supported names. To selenium, `"Chromium"` is no more valid than `"xyzzy"` -- it simply doesn't know what the word means.

Comment: Have you installed the chrome driver? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: That seemed to solve the problem in combination with adding a symlink /usr/bin/google-chrome -> /usr/bin/chromium-browser. Not sure if either works alone. Will try at home. Does installing selenium2library via `pip install` automatically set up the ChromeDriver when Chrome (_not_ Chromium) is installed?
If you file this as an answer, I'd accept that solution.

Comment: @jotrocken Oh, I thought Chromium was just another name for Chrome. "You live and learn"

Comment: @BryanOakley your solution works even without setting the symbolic link. Can you post this as solution, hinting that the chrome driver also works for Chromium, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that "chromium" isn't a name that the selenium library knows about. You can't use just any name. Use "chrome" rather than "chromium", and make sure that the [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) is installed in some folder in your path -- it doesn't get installed by default.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys
${options.binary_location}    Set Variable    /var/blah/chromium
Create Webdriver    Chrome    my_alias    chrome_options=${options}
Go To    http://www.robotframework.org/
```

Comment: `Evaluating expression 'sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()' failed: NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`
As it seems Python modules cannot be imported directly. What do I have to do to access sys.modules?

Comment: The first line has a second parameter to Evaluate to import sys, so it should be defined. Perhaps a copy/paste mistake - sys is not supposed to be part of the eval expression.

Comment: Indeed there was a copy problem. It works, which is great! But I think the solution by @Bryan is more convenient. I am fixing the path to the chromium browser in your solution.

Comment: I did not know that ChromeDriver also searched the path for Chromium, but it makes sense that it does. Create Webdriver is only a last resort. Should I delete this? A better solution if Chromium is not on the path would be to adjust the path and use Open Browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only accept one solution. @ombre42 your answer solves the problem and shows how to create a WebDriver from inside a robot script. I see no reason why you should delete it.